# Rails 4: nested resources with non-standard identifiers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Let's take a look at nested resource example, the following is the model:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads, :order => 'time_start'
end

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :magazine
end
```

and the routing so far looks like this:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

this automatically yields URLs like `/magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id`.

However, I'd like to have slightly different URLs scheme, much more "magazine"-centric. General nested URL scheme should look like that: `/magazines/:id/:ad_num/component`, where:

- ":id" is what was ":magazine_id" in standard generated routing URLs, a primary key for magazine object in database
- ":ad_num" is a way to identify a single ad inside a given magazine, but it's *not* a database identifier, but instead an index in array of ads in a single magazine
- There should be no generic "show" action (i.e. `/magazines/:id/:ad_num`), but instead there are multiple components inside an "ad", which are shown using several different actions

I'd like to have no `AdsController` at all, all these routes should point to various actions in `MagazineController` instead, for example `magazines/5/1/title` should point to `MagazineController` => `title` with `params[:id] = 5` and `params[:ad_num] = 1`.

Of course, a useful URL helper like `title_ad_magazine(@magazine, @ad)` would be most helpful.

How do I do that in new Rails routing DSL?

Answer (score 1):

You can produce custom route with those param keys like this

```
 get '/magazines/:id/:ad_num/title' => 'magazine#title', as: :magazine_ads_title
```

you will have `parmams[:id]` and `params[:ad_num]` matched to those sections of the url

You don't need to use the as: option but you may find it helpful to produce my intuitive url helpers